# Encrypt and decrypt password websphere

Tags: java, websphere

In websphere (SMC module)m i can encrypt password in generating encrypt string

For example i encrypt "test" this return => a6uOgV_EhT

How can i decrypt this text in java?

Comment: When you encrypt it *how*?

Answer (score 1):

It is very poor security practice to ever decrypt a password, or even to be able to do so.

Typically when receiving a password, you hash that password using a hashing algorithm, then match the hash against the hash stored in your database. This way you can not decrypt it, and the only person who can know the password is the user. It is also a good idea to append something the user's password prior to hashing in order to prevent rainbow table look up should your database data leak.